# Converting a list of lists into a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list of lists:

```
x = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5]]
```

to a dictionary of lists where the index of each list is the key of the dictionary (starting at 1):

```
new_dictionary = {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 3, 4], 4: [1, 2, 5]}
```

I will be working with large lists, is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Keep in mind that Python sequences are 0-indexed, not 1-indexed.

Comment: Besides: Why do you want that?

Comment: @tobias_k - I'm curious to know that as well. A dictionary where each key is the index of an input list is functionally identical to the list. It seems pointless.

Comment: Might be an example of the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I'm hoping it's not an XY problem!  All I'm trying to do is get my data to be congruent with some existing data.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: What do you mean by making your data congruent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `dict` constructor takes an iterable of tuples, where the first item is the key and the second is the value.

This is exactly what `enumerate` returns:

```
new_dictionary = dict(enumerate(x))
```

Then `new_dictionary` will contain:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 3], 2: [1, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 5]}
```

Notice that the first key is `0`, not `1`. If you want to start from one or something else, use the `start=1` parameter with `enumerate`:

```
>>> dict(enumerate(x, start=1))
{1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 3, 4], 4: [1, 2, 5]}
```

I am curious about your use case, however, since a list and a dictionary can be used in very similar ways:

```
>>> x[0]
[1, 2]
>>> new_dictionary[0]
[1, 2]
```

Are you sure you really need a dictionary for this?

Comment: Use `start=1`, then it's good (assuming that OP _really_ wants it that way)

Comment: With `start=1`, the keys will no longer match the original indices.

Comment: Yeah, the example and the descriptions are contradictory: "where the index of each list is the key of the dictionary" and then starting from 1. Good point.

Comment: Great, this works.  How do I use `start = 1` ?

Comment: @AndrewEarl, see the last example (interactive, beginning with the `>>>` prompt)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dict comprehension` like this:

```
new_dictionary = {index + 1: value for index, value in enumerate(x)}
```